# Selenium on raspberry - headless firefox not working as expected

Tags: python, headless, selenium, webdriver

i wrote a python code using selenium to interact with a headless browser. I altered the code a little for the use on the raspberry. The code for the PC works fine, but on the raspberry it stops to respond when trying to click on the button on the webpage. After a few minutes i get the following timeout error:

```
`  File "AntenneReduced.py", line 52, in <module>
    element1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "gl-pl-pause")))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

After the timeout it only has a slow response to commands until reboot.

I'm using a Raspberry3 B+ headless, python3 V3.5.3, Mozilla Firefox 52.9.0 and geckodriver V17

Could it be, that the elements of the webpage are different on the raspberry and hence can't be located?

`The code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[23]:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

#binary = FirefoxBinary('/home/pi/Dateien/usr/bin/firefox')

import time

STREAM='http://antennebayern.radio.de/'
print("vor display")
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
print("bis display")
opt=webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
opt.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opt, executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')
print("driver geladen")

# In[24]:
driver.get(STREAM)
print("Seite laden geht")

try:
    element1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "gl-pl-pause")))
    print("Button ist schon geklickt")

except:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "gl-pl-play")))
    element.click();
    print("Button klicken geht")

# In[25]:
demo_div = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".player__song > span:nth-child(2)")

driver.quit()
display.stop()
```